# Is exiting a function with an empty return statement good/bad practice?

Tags: if-statement, coding-style, return

I've seen many examples and this is getting me more than curious

The two examples are the following :

- Having `return;`at the end of a void function, this is flat out ridiculous.
- Using `return;`in the middle of a function to break out of it. I don't like it.

The following example might clarify the second case (the first one being obvious):

```
- SomeMethodThatReturnsSomethingOrNot(var param1){

    if (param1 == null){

         CallThisMethod();
         return;
    }

    CallThisOtherMethod(param1);

}
```

To a lot of people, this is fine and clear. To me, it is *acceptable* at best.

Why not simply using an `if else`? You avoid the need to `return` nothing in the middle of the code, it doesn't decrease readability, and, well, I don't know what else to say, it just looks like a better practice to me.

```
- SomeMethodThatReturnsSomethingOrNot(var param1){

        if (param1 == null){
             CallThisMethod();
        }else{
             CallThisOtherMethod(param1);
        }

    }
```

Now I'd like to emphasize the simplicity of the example here, I know somethign sexier could be made but lets just pretend its something a bit more complex than a `null` check, that requires the same kind of `if-return`instead`of if-else` technique.

So, what are everyone's thoughts?

I've been strongly against returning something when the method is either void, or when I don't actually want to return anything. If I end up in that situation, I like to rethink my architecture because it shouldn't happen.

Am I completely wrong/right or is there some discussing space here?

Comment: it make sense if instead `CallThisMethod();` would be a bit code and instaed `CallThisOtherMethod` would be a lot of code

Comment: Voted to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Grundy if it's more than 1 or 2 lines it would be hidden in a method anyway, so most of the time it is pretty much exactly like my example (except for the names).

Comment: @zenith You're right, maybe I should put that in programmers.stackexchange

Comment: @Zil, not in every case you can move some lines of code to method

Comment: The first thing i learned at school it that you can  have only one return per function.

Comment: @GilSand I'm curious, after 6 years, what are your thoughts about this question nowadays?

Comment: @FabianoLothor Well I'm still pretty much in agreement with my younger self. I don't like my functions to have more than one exit point and I usually try to write keeping that (among many other things) in mind. If I see it, I won't fix it, I don't consider it a big code smell. But I'll do my best to not write one myself.

Same as returning null, I'd prefer return a valid, healthy object that is just empty but still usable.

If my void function has to exit before the end, I probably need 2 smaller functions.

Comment: @GilSand thanks for share your thoughts, I recently had a bad day because I've the same sentiment that you've. I really agree with you that it's something fine to follow both approaches, but I prefer to don't return empty. Unfortunately my team leader doesn't agree and basically forced me to rewrite the function using an empty return, otherwise he wouldn't accept the PR. I didn't receive any strong argument to change my thoughts, so I research a bit and arrived to your question.

Comment: In the end, following your architect is the way to you.

It's better that the whole team follows one single style and set of guidelines that some people don't agree with. The other solution is that everyone follows his own guidelines and it's 100% gonna be different for each dev, which means the code base will be a mess.

I prefer a code base that is coherent but that I disagree with, rather than a codebase that is incoherent, and where I disagree with some of the code that I didn't write.

Answer (score 7):

You might be interested in looking into the subject of SESE (single entry, single exit) and Dijkstra's thoughts on the subject which kind of prompted this style.

It's worth noting though that Dijkstra's thoughts are often misunderstood. He was advocating practices during an era where a lot of people were writing code in straight assembly. In assembly, you're often allowed to jump from any instruction to any other. That's where the notion of "single-entry" comes from: it's extremely confusing to jump from one function into the middle of another.

"Single-exit" is often misinterpreted to mean exiting a function *from* only one place. It actually meant exiting a function *to only one place*. It becomes extremely confusing if you returned out of a function to a place other than the site in which it was called.

Nevertheless, a lot people today continue to think of "single-exit" to mean, "exit *from* only one place in a function", and advocates often promote the style you're suggesting.

I won't go into which one is better or worse. It's inevitably going to be subjective. But there are some things worth thinking about.

**Explicit Cleanup**

The idea of exiting from only one place in a function was largely popularized during eras that required explicit cleanup in many functions with respect to their resources -- something like this:

```
function f()
    allocate_resources()
    ...
    deallocate_resources()
end
```

We can see if we introduced any kind of early return statement in such a function that we could easily forget to deallocate the resources and end up with some kind of resource leak. In these cases, the suggestion to favor return statements only at the end of a function become significantly more useful to prevent human errors.

**Exception-Handling**

Exception-handling is now a common feature in many modern languages. With exception-handling, there can be implicit exits all over a function. Example:

```
function f()
    list = create_list()   -- could throw
    list.insert(123)       -- could throw
    connect_to_server()    -- could throw
    if x == 0 then
         add_some_widget() -- could throw
    end
end
```

In these cases, any line of code could have an implicit exit point from the function as a result of an exception being thrown. As a result, it's impossible to make the control flow totally predictable. There too, comes an inevitable need for automated resource management where it's up to the compiler (or garbage collector) to clean up resources automatically, not up to the developer to do it manually, because it becomes too impractical to do it manually with so many implicit exit points in a function.

**Conclusion**

So these are some of the considerations to make. I'm personally in the middle-lower end of the spectrum (if "low" means putting returns anywhere, and "high" means only at the bottom). But it's all up to you where you find your comfort zone, and what kind of code you find easiest to understand and maintain.

In my humble opinion we could go cross-eyed trying to analyze the merits of exactly how a function is written down to every single line of code, but I'd have to appeal to a pragmatic sort of view of like just test it well, make sure the interface and documentation is clear, make sure the implementation maybe passes a basic litmus test of not causing people's brains to explode, and then ship it.